# Randomly pick a zero in a 2d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2d numpy array like this:

```
board = numpy.array([[ 0,  0,  2,  2],
    [ 4,  0,  2,  0],
    [ 2,  2,  2,  2],
    [ 0,  0,  0, 16]])
```

I want to choose one of the zeros, and replace it with something else. I came up with a solution myself, but I'm looking for a better way; perhaps using a numpy function like `choice` but for a 2d array.

```
zeros = np.where(board == 0)
r = np.random.randint(len(zeros[0]))
z1 = zeros[0][r]
z2 = zeros[1][r]
board[z1, z2] = 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the indices where `board == 0`, convert them to a linear index so that you can use `np.random.choice` (because this method only accepts 1-D arrays) and then convert that randomly chosen linear index to the corresponding 2D index and make the replacement.

```
import numpy as np

board = np.array([[ 0,  0,  2,  2],
                  [ 4,  0,  2,  0],
                  [ 2,  2,  2,  2],
                  [ 0,  0,  0, 16]])

zeros = np.argwhere(board == 0) # Indices where board == 0
indices = np.ravel_multi_index([zeros[:, 0], zeros[:, 1]], board.shape) # Linear indices

ind = np.random.choice(indices) # Randomly select your index to replace

board[np.unravel_index(ind, board.shape)] = 100 # Perform the replacement

>>> board
    [[  0   0   2   2]
     [  4   0   2 100]
     [  2   2   2   2]
     [  0   0   0  16]]
```

Comment: why not just do "ind = np.random.randint(len(zeros))" instead of all that ravel and unraveling?

Comment: That's what he did and he's asking for another version, where `np.random.choice` can be used. And this is what I came up with for this purpose.

Comment: first of all 'he' is me :) and I didn't say `np.random.choice` should be used. I was looking for an alternative because it can not be used for a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

The method you're using seems fine. Could be sped-up/streamlined a bit.

Python's [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) works fine with the arrays of `zeros` zipped:

```py
zeros
# is:
(array([0, 0, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3], dtype=int64),
 array([0, 1, 1, 3, 0, 1, 2], dtype=int64))

list(zip(*zeros))
# output:
# [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 3), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2)]

import random
random.choice(list(zip(*zeros)))
# (3, 1)
```

That returns a 2-element tuple - one index per axis, which can be used for `[]` assignment:

```py
board[random.choice(list(zip(*zeros)))] = 100
board
# output:
array([[  0,   0,   2,   2],
       [  4,   0,   2,   0],
       [  2,   2,   2,   2],
       [  0,   0, 100,  16]])
```